# Azure Data Factory / calling a stored procedure, place results in a file

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, resultset

I'm not familiar with working in an Azure Data Factory, but have a work requirement to have some processing run in that environment.

I have a stored procedure that creates a result set. I've read about a lookup step. That may be what I need to use. I want to call the stored procedure and put the result set into a mass-storage file. Ideally I'd like the process insert pipe delimiters between the columns, but if no Azure process does that, I can put my own delimiters in the stored procedure directly.

What is the process in Data Factory to use to call a stored procedure and put the data set into a mass-storage file?

TIA

Trying to research my options at this point. As mentioned, appears a  lookup step may be the process to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **copy activity** for this.

Here is a demo I have reproduced.

Sample Stored procedure for selecting the data:

```
create  or  alter  procedure sp1
as
begin
select  *  from copy_table3
end
```

In your stored procedure create your result set and select from it.

My sample `copy_data3` table:

[image]

In copy activity source use stored procedure option after giving SQL dataset.

[image]

In the drop down you can select your stored procedure and if it has parameters, you can import those above.

In sink I have used a blob csv file, and this is **my result csv** after execution.

[image]